# PHP dynamic multidimensional array with a hyphen included in its name

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, syntax

I am trying to create a multidimensional array that is strictly based on this xml template (structure):

```
<invoice>
    <type></type>
    <transport></transport>
    <items>
        <item-ordered>
            <name></name>
            <quantity></quantity>
        </item-ordered>
    </items>
</invoice>
```

I am a php newbie, so i tried to solve it using basic knowledge of php:

```
//This is from where I get all data for populating my XML/array structure
$products = $params['order']->getProducts();
$prName = array_column($products, 'product_name');
$prQuantity = array_column($products, 'product_quantity');

//Populating arrays with data
$item-ordered = array();
$items = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
    $item-ordered =  array (            
        "name" => $prName[$i],
        "quantity" => $prQuantity[$i]
    );
    array_push($items,$item-ordered);    //using a hyphen appears to be invalid
)

$invoice = array (
    "type" => "code:INVOICE",
    "transport" => $customerTransport,
    "items" => $items
)
```

but I run into a problem when trying to use a variable/array name that includes a dash(hyphen).

So my 1st question is whether my solution is right. If it is than I would like to know how do I deal with that hyphen issue. The final array should have exactly the same structure as the XML file showed above, I cannot change the XML file itself.

Comment: Just `$item_ordered`?

Comment: PHP (and most common languages with a similar c-derivative syntax) does not allow the `-` character in an identifier. In PHP variable names must match something similar to `$[0-9a-zA-Z_]+`. Consider what would happen if you wanted to use subtraction on variables if they could have hyphens in their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **$item_ordered** as a variable name or any other name, but don't use a normal serialization with `serialize($item_ordered)` function, you have to serialize the array by your self and write the XML in a way that you change the root node  "item_ordered" to "item-ordered"...you can take a look at PHP Array Serialization on this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#109953, or simply serialize it  and use `str_replace` to change the node's name in the serialized result, so the code should look like this:

```
    $item_ordered = array();
    $items = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
        $item_ordered =  array (            
            "name" => $prName[$i],
            "quantity" => $prQuantity[$i]
        );
        array_push($items, 
str_replace("item_ordered", "item-ordered", serialize($item_ordered)));    
    }

    echo serialize($items);
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer, but I think I might solved the problem - i can create the array using the "key&value" notation - so i can write sth like this `"item-ordered" => array(...)` , am I right? 

So I need to know whether it is posssible to create this array multiple times using that "key&value" notation - in case of having more than 1 order - like this:
`<items>
        <item-ordered>
            <name></name>
            <quantity></quantity>
        </item-ordered>
<item-ordered>
            <name></name>
            <quantity></quantity>
        </item-ordered>
    </items>`

Comment: You are welcome, and Yes i got your idea you can do that, and you can write a new code to do the job, OR you can use my already written code and save your time :)